# Launching fragments from Navigation Drawer causes app to crash

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

As the question states i am trying to launch a fragment from the Android Studio prebuilt Navigation Drawer template.

I tried following this guys video here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H4R-hz56oBA . During testing sometimes his way would work and sometimes it would not but, I always used the same bit of code.

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        Facebook facebookFrag = new Facebook();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
       manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.homeLanding,facebookFrag,facebookFrag.getTag()).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_tools) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

In theory the fragment called Facebook would replace the default fragment I named homeLanding when the item Gallery was clicked in the Navigation Drawer. Any ideas?

Update: Looks like I needed to implement the OnFragmentInteractionListener in my MainActivity.

[cyclic inheritance involving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38058343/cyclic-inheritance-involving?rq=1)

Solved my issue

Comment: Use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this If you do not understand the stack trace, add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code, and my drawer is a global variable:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        //Use this code to set the starting fragment:
        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragments_container,
                    new VendasFragment()).commit();
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_vendas);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.menu_vendas);
        }
    }


@Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
            switch (item.getItemId()){

                case (R.id.nav_vendas):
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragments_container,
                            new VendasFragment()).commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.menu_vendas);
                    break;

                case (R.id.nav_clientes):
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragments_container,
                            new ClienteFragment()).commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.menu_clientes);
                    break;

                case (R.id.nav_estoque):
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragments_container,
                            new EstoqueFragment()).commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.menu_estoque);
                    break;

                case (R.id.nav_estatistica):
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragments_container,
                            new EstatisticaFragment()).commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.menu_estatistica);
                    break;

                case (R.id.nav_fornecedores):
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragments_container,
                            new FornecedorFragment()).commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.menu_fornecedores);
                    break;

                case (R.id.nav_backup):
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragments_container,
                            new BackupFragment()).commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.menu_backup);
                    break;

                case (R.id.nav_config):
                    break;

                case (R.id.nav_conta_receber):
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragments_container,
                            new ContasReceberFragment()).commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.menu_contas_receber);
                    break;

                case (R.id.nav_contas_pagar):
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragments_container,
                            new ContasPagarFragment()).commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.menu_contas_pagar);
                    break;
            }

            drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }
```